# How do you apply an element on the left of a permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am looking at the set $G=\{1,2,3\}$. I take the subgroup:

$$H=\{(), (1,2)\} < S_G$$

I want to find $G/H$. I take the definition of $G/H$:

$$\{1H, 2H, 3H\}$$

$$\{1\{(), (1,2)\}, 2\{(), (1,2)\}, 3\{(), (1,2)\}\}$$

But how do you evaluate something like:

$$1\{(), (1,2)\}$$

I am pretty sure it becomes:

$$\{1(), 1(1,2)\}$$

After this I am not certain. My guess would be:

$$\{1, 2\}$$

But I am not sure how permutation groups should be evaluated from left to right. (My book does the evaluation from right to left.)

Comment: In any group, $gH$ is defined to be shorthand for $\{gh:h\in H\}$. Though your notation is incredibly confusing. $1$, $2$ and $3$ are not group elements so you can't multiply them in this way.

Comment: $G/H$ doesn't make sense because $H$ is a group but $G$ has no group structure. Did you mean $S_G/H$?

Comment: @ZachGershkoff: I was testing some small cases for a larger problem. I do not believe I am allowed to discuss the question that motivated this question, but I believe there was probably a flaw in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have mixed up $\{1,2,3\}$ and the group of permutations over that set. Once you use the right definition for $G=S_{\{1,2,3\}}$ then the cosets make sense: for example, the product $(13)H$ of the permutation $(13)$ and the subgroup $H$ becomes $\{(13)(id), (13)(12)\}$ and $(13)(12) = (123)$, so $(13)H = \{(13), (123)\}$. $G/H$ is the set of all these products.

Comment: Hmm, I was testing out small cases for a larger problem. After reviewing your answer and the comments, I believe the question that motivated this question has a flaw in it. I would post the original but, I do not believe I am allowed to do so. Thanks for the help!